# The name of the instance from the user. You can't, but if you need it that way?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

GUI application. The user enters the state registration plate of the car: "a123bc45", or "a123bc456" - three letters and five (six) digits. This string should become the name of an instance of the Car class. The code for verifying user input is ready.

[image]

[image]

Comment: _"This string should become the name of an instance of the Car class."_ - why? What problem are you trying to solve? Also, please don't post pictures of code. The pictures are almost completely useless.

Comment: the instance name is an identifier. The instance will change, move. Can I take the number in order as the instance name? And look for a way to identify the object I need to work with it and their set.

Comment: Try an online search before asking a question here. It is what I always do, anyways. I found a solution [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-python#:~:text=is%20pythonforbeginners.com-,String%20Into%20Variable%20Name%20in%20Python%20Using%20the%20vars(),like%20the%20globals()%20function.).

Comment: Based on the above site, you can do `myVars = vars() ; myVars[varname] = value ; print(varname)`. I put this on a single line, hence the semicolons. `varname` is the name of your variable, in this case the inputted string. `value` is it's value, in this case and instance of the `Car` class.